# How to make Compose key to work in Firefox under Linux?

Tags: linux, firefox

I have the [Compose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) key working well under KEdit, KConsole, LibreOffice, but not in FireFox.

How do I make it work in FireFox? I cannot enter ANY additional characters at all.

I have read a hint to add GTK_IM_MODULE="xim" in /etc/environment but this does not affect anything.

Currently I have to enter characters in KEdit and copy them to FireFox.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're following these directions: https://web.archive.org/web/20210918084400/https://wiki.kubuntu.org/ComposeKey

Did you follow the "Persistent Configuration" directions?

Comment: I have added GTK_IM_MODULE="xim" to /etc/environment. Starting FireFox with this variable explicitely does not help either.

Comment: In /etc/environment it should be: GTK_IM_MODULE=xim firefox

Comment: I would also expect you to need to restart X after this. The Wiki claims the "Persistent Configuration" is the preferred way of doing this though.

Comment: of course I rebooted.

Comment: Well I have just checked and it seems that regardless of what I do, I have GTK_IM_MODULE="cedilla" How can I change this? Cedilla is not installed.

Comment: I changed it to xim, but nothing changed anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry Anixx, I'm all out of ideas :-(

Comment: echo "GTK_IM_MODULE=xim firefox" >> ~/.zshrc